# Joining Lists and Splitting Strings

Tags: python, oop, language-design

I have some previous experience with C++ and just getting started up with Python. I read this text from [Dive into Python](http://www.diveintopython.net/) :

[image]

In my experience, a general idea is, if you want to perform an operation on object 'O', you call a method on that object to do it.

Eg. If I have a list object, and I want to get summation of all elements, I would do something like :

```
listObject.getSumOfAllElements()
```

However, the call given in above book excerpt looks a little odd to me. To me this would make more sense :

```
return (["%s=%s" % (k, v) for k, v in params.items()]).join(";")
```

i.e. join all the elements of the list as a string, and here, use this parameter `';'` as a delimiter.

Is this a design difference or just syntactically a little different than what I am thinking ?

---

Edit:

For completion, the book says this a little later :

[image]

Comment: Yes, it's kind of backwards as the ";" is your object here, on which you're performing a method.

Comment: Do you mean to ask why is it `string.join(list)` instead of `list.join(string)`?

Comment: @BhargavRao Yes, exactly!

Comment: Aaah thanks @BhargavRao It has detailed explanation already on the page you posted. Should I raise this to be closed or plain delete it ?

Comment: @AmitTomar Nope. Leave it as it is. Other's will benefit from this. thefourtheye's answer is good. Do accept it if you also feel so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is this a design difference or just syntactically a little different than what I am thinking?

Yes, I think it is by design. The `join` function is intentionally generic, so that it can be used with any iterable (including iterator objects and generators). This avoids implementing `join` for `list`, `tuple`, `set` etc separately.